# Translation showing up in backend but not on display or user registration

Tags: i18n-l10n

I translated some fields, everything looks fine in the back end. String are successfully translated to French.

However they don't show up for user registration/profile modification, they don't show up on exposed filters or views.

Everything looks fine and translated, but not working...must be a setting? I have tried the language detection, views setting for user language, refreshed strings, updated, cleared cache...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the language detection settings (admin/config/regional/language/configure). How are they set, try to put on URL all up in the list and see if this works.

Comment: Detection is set up to URL (on top) and also user, translation works fine for  everything else, meny link, core ect....

Answer (score 0):

do you also use the [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module ?

**tmgmt is not enough !!** this module is meant to help the translators and to use external translations servives.

probably you need to enable more translation modules from i18n like field translations, [entity translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) (seperate module) etc.

Comment: I have ALL necessary modules installed and enabled

Comment: what do you see if you search for "I dont't care" in the core translation interface ?

Comment: I see the strings are there and translated properly:  I don't care
field:field_drinking:#allowed_values:I don't care field_drinking:#allowed_values:I don't care zh-hans fr th edit delete - fr is translated indeed

Comment: site is online and you can login and look inside if you want: username: 1 password: vuxisandbox   URL  http://sandbox.vuxi.com/

Comment: ok - i see, you got this values there in the field, why aren't you using taxonomy reference fields ?

Comment: for your used list select field here's the workaround: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/97966/3218

Comment: The last comment with for automatic, I have no idea what t() means and how to implement. I have all modules installed, everything looks translated. But drop down selects are not translated in user account and exposed filters drop down selects are not translated either...;(

Comment: this is a bug - you need to invoke the hook from the comment above in a custom module, or move to taxonomies for each of your select list field